# golang test error: cannot find package "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert" in any of:

Tags: go, testify

My import looks like this below:

```
import (
"testing"

"github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)
```

when I try try running 'go test' I get the error message:

```
cannot find package "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert" in any of:
/Users/[username]/go/src/github.com/[group_name]/[project_name]/vendor/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert (vendor tree)
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert (from $GOROOT)
/Users/[username]/go/src/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert (from $GOPATH)
FAIL    github.com/[group_name]/[project_name]/lib/briteverify [setup failed]
```

So it appears the last line is the issue, where it says in .../lib/briteverify it cannot find github.com/stretchr/testify/assert. However, I have this as an import so I don't know why it would throw this error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you run `go get github.com/stretchr/testify/assert` to get the assert package?

Comment: ahhhhhhh nope! Brand new to golang and aside from doing that once a week ago I forgot. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Moving the answer here for others in the future.

You need to both import the package and run `go get github.com/package/path` to install the package.